# Adhesive for Samsung refrigerator cooling panel

Tags: refrigerator

Inside the Samsung fridge, cool air would typically circulate through the holes indicated below using green arrows. However, someone accidentally pulled on this panel instead of the evaporator cover below it. Now the foam at the sides (indicated in red arrows) no longer have a perfect seal with the fridge wall. Is there a special adhesive used to affix the foam? There are no screws (just foam that was stuck to the walls).

[image: Cooling panel]

Comment: I'm not sure it really matters where the air comes out.